# Any way to query deleted objects in AD only for a particular OU? C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Is there any way to query the deleted objects in AD only for a particular OU rather than for the entire domain?

C#.

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you want to get help in this forum you'll need to show an attempted solution. Meaning a question must be accompanied by code.

Comment: Use DirectorySearcher. It has a helpful Property called SearchRoot. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)